# How to see that series $|\sin(1/n^2)|$ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to see that series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\sin(1/n^{2})|$ converge or diverge? That is, to see if $\sum_{n}\sin(1/n^{2})$ absolutely converges.

I know that for all $n$ in $\mathbb N$, $\sin(1/n^2)<1/n^2$, but is that fact useful here? Could someone tell me how to show that?

Comment: Look for the term "comparison test" in your textbook.  Beyond what you've already done, that's all you need.

Comment: what do you know about $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: @noctusraid I know it is converge, andc therefore  sin(1/n^2) is converge. But it is alternating, what I do not know is that how to show that it is absolutely converge.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have learnt about that. But I cannot find something to tell me about the convergence or divergence of absolute value.

Comment: You have $$\left |\sin{\frac{1}{n^2}}  \right |\leqslant \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: @Daniil If so then it works!  But so far I cannot prove the inequality... Could you please also give me some hint to prove your inquality? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Y.X. : Since $\sin(1/n^2)$ is positive, it is the same as its absolute value.  So from $\sin(1/n^2) \le 1/n^2$ you get $|\sin(1/n^2)| \le 1/n^2$.  Then apply the comparison test and you're done. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to prove the inequality $$\left|\sin\frac1{n^2}\right|\le\frac1{n^2},$$ it follows from:

**Claim:** $|\sin x|\le |x|$ for every $x$.

**Proof:** Suppose $x\ne0$. By the mean value theorem, there exists a number $a$ such that

$$\sin x - \sin 0 = \cos(a)(x-0),\tag1$$
since the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$. Take absolute values of both sides of (1), then use the fact that $|\cos a|\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Compare with the convergent series $\sum n^{-2}$, then

$$ \lim \frac{ \sin (n^{-2}) }{n^{-2}} =_{t = n^{-2}} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin t }{t} = 1 $$

Comment: This means replacing $sin\dfrac1{n^2}$\ with the *equivalent* at infinity $\dfrac1{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges by the p-series test, Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\sin (\frac{1}{n^2})|$ converges by using the inequality mentioned by you and the comparison test.

Comment: But as I mentioned, it is alternating, so how can I see the behavior of absolute value?

Comment: @Y.X. The series, since it contains the absolute value, is not alternating.

Comment: But is it the fact that for all n in **N*, sin(1/n^2)<(1/n^2), we haven't been told that $ |sin(1/n^2)|<(1/n^2)$, so I cannot see that the inequality works here.

Comment: The inequality can be proved by considering the curves of y=x and y=|sin(x)|

Answer (score 0):

For all $x$ $$\sin (x) = \sum^{\infty}_{i=0} \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!} x^{2i+1} 
$$ So $$\sin\left(\frac 1 {n^k} \right)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=0} \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!} n^{-(2i+1)k} $$ and, by comparison with p-series, each term converge as soon as $k>1$.

Moreover, you do not need to consider absolute values since $n\geq 1$.

For $k=2$, having $$\sin\left(\frac 1 {n^2} \right)=\frac{1}{n ^2}-\frac{1}{6 n^6}+\frac{1}{120
   n^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{14}}\right)$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac 1 {n^2} \right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n ^2}-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n ^6}+\frac{1}{120}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n ^{10}}+\cdots=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{\pi ^6}{5670}+\frac{\pi ^{10}}{11226600}$$